# What is the best way to code a full Dojo web application?

Tags: dojo

I am trying to code a medium sized full web application based off dojo.

I have a basic BorderContainer that is placed at the document.body.

[image: BorderContainer]

In order to make code maintainable and easy to read, I want to put fully contained widgets/modules in each of the sections.  That can be simply added by a couple lines such as...

```js
var topTabs = new TopTabs();
top.addChild(topTabs);
```

And then I want to stitch them all together so that they can invoke work in each of the other widgets, in order to follow the MVC model.

So for instance, one example that I would like to insert the following widget that is fully contained into the top section that looks something like...

[image: Example]

So my question is....

What is the best way to create these fully defined and encapsulated widgets/modules?

Since my widgets will also contain other Dijits, then are template based widgets the route to go?  Or is it better to create widgets/modules that are purely programmatically defined?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends how much you are familiar / comfortable with declarative/html (templated) versus programmatic/javascript. You can definitely go both routes;

I seldom use templates, which are static by nature and mean two set of entities in two languages, usually two files, to account for. Besides, with dojo/dom-construct &  dojo/dom-style, I have an effective dynamic replacement to html templates, allowing to build self-contained complex widgets
jc

Comment: Thanks for the reply JC.  I personally prefer programmatic.  However, I am having issues with that as well.  Maybe you could answer my other question I just posted.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848279/why-doesnt-this-dojo-snippet-work

Answer (score 1):

Your going to want to read about making custom dijits (widgets) - https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/recipes/custom_widget/

templates vs programmatic is more of a personal choice. templates are much easier for a UX (non dev) to work with.  i like to use templates as it reduces the clutter in my js files  i prefer to keep things separate logic (js), style (css), and structure/layout (html).

Comment: The Programatic examples there are pretty lacking.  I wish they would do some more complex examples.

Comment: i thought that at first but after you get it you'll realize they are ok.

Comment: also remember dojo is a toolkit not a framework.  eg, a bunch of tools not a forced way to do things.  we've been moving away from using a lot of the dijit stuff and use mostly the core stuff + dGrid & dStore.