# Why doesn't this Dojo snippet work?

Tags: dojo

So when I try to insert a div into the BorderContainer, my page does not load.  What is going on?  What am I doing wrong?

If I comment out the banner lines, the border container loads just fine.  If I put the div back in, the page no longer loads.

[image]

Comment: any reason you want a div with innerHtml as "title'? you can set that as content to the top contentpane like top.set("content","Title")?

Comment: Also do you get any error while you are adding div?

Comment: addChild takes a widget and div is not a widget

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  Basically I want to create a banner programmatically that is very simple.  A div with text and a class will accomplish what I want.  Seems a little overkill to create a widget for that.  I thought that I could accomplish with domConstruct.create

Comment: No errors that I can see in firebug.

Comment: I guess I can use top.set("content", "Title"), but it seems a little goofy to do that if you wanted something very complex in there.

Comment: well you can set complex widgets within a contentpane. I have done that multiple times. A contentpane is very similar to a div in html but with more features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have `top` define as [ContentPane](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/layout/ContentPane.html) [API](https://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dijit/layout/ContentPane). and `Banner` as domNode. so to set a domNode you need to set content.

```
top.set('content', banner);
```

if you want to add a widget (think of these as code, not HTML) to a content page you need to add it's dom.

```
top.set('content', bannerWidget.domNode);
```

or

```
bannerWidget.startup();
top.addChild(bannerWidget);
```

if you pass a widget it must subclass dijit/_WidgetBase and you need to call startup on it.

I prefer to use a single widget per pane.  i have multiple widgets wrap them up into a single widget.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  If a ContentPane can only have content, how can it accept a widget as a child?  Is there another type of  pane that can be used?

Comment: the content itself can be a widget and you can have multiple widgets within a contenpane

Comment: ps.  we have found it' s easier to do responsive apps without the use of the dojo *Pane widgets and just go native.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only need to inject html content indeed the right approach is to use the 'content' attribute as described by denov and Manjunatha.

In that particular case also, as said by Manjunatha, you don't need the domConstruct part and maybe not the div, and finally you can provide content in the instantiation statement, so the compact form would be, :`var top = new ContentPane({..., content: title});`.

You can then add widgets to top by using top.addChild(aWidget) - e.g.for a menu bar, which would then appear below the content (the title). But aWidget has to be a widget, which banner is not.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jh9DC/21/) Initially, content for the pane is foo! bar! and on click of the button "Click" content gets changed to a Button

**

- HTML

**

```
<div id="target"></div>
<div id="click">

</div>
```

**

- JS Code

**

```
dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");

dojo.ready(function() {
    var bc = new dijit.layout.BorderContainer( {
        'class': 'theBorderContainer'
    }, 'target');

    var p1 = new dijit.layout.ContentPane( {
        region: 'center',
        content: '<p>foo! bar!</p>'
    });
    var p2 = new dijit.layout.ContentPane( {
        region: 'top',
        content: '<p>top!</p>'
    });

  var btn = new dijit.form.Button({
  name:"button",
  title:"Hello",
  label:"Hello"
  });

  var btn1 = new dijit.form.Button({
  name:"click",
  title:"Click",
  label:"Click",
  onClick:function(evt){
  p1.set('content',btn);
  }
  },click);


    bc.startup();

    bc.addChild(p1);
    bc.addChild(p2);
    p1.startup();
});
```

**

- CSS code

**

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.theBorderContainer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
}
```